I want to create an object from an array and want to iterate for the keys of the object
I have an Object with x attributes.
class Test {

 a1;
 a2;
 a3;
 a4;
 a5;

}

I have an array with values in determined positions, so I always know that a1 is in position 0.
arrayWithValues = [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5];

I want to create a static method in Test class to create an object givin and array of values.
createNewTestObject (param: []) {

... With a constructor if it is needed. 

}

I want to iterate for every attribute from the class and create a new instance.
Is that possible?

Please [edit] the code here to be a [mre] where your issue is immediately apparent when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs. Right now your class has no field annotations, nor are they initialized. (And public is sort of a no-op there, and mostly just distracting). And arrayWithValues has not been declared, and neither have the values named a1, a2, etc. You can certainly iterate your array, but that doesn't create an instance; you can only create a true instance with new. I have more questions than suggestions so it would be very helpful if you'd [edit] to clarify.

This question is similar to: How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is tagged [[ŧag:typescript]] for some reason, but I don't see any types in the code (apart from :[], which appears to be wrong). What types do your properties have? What type does the array have?

The array does not contain names, it only contains values. You have to explicitly specify the name of each property that you want to assign:
function createNewTestObject(param) {
  const obj = new Test;
  obj.a1 = param[0];
  obj.a2 = param[1];
  obj.a3 = param[2];
  obj.a4 = param[3];
  obj.a5 = param[4];
}

You can (or probably should) do this in the constructor of Test instead of a separate method, but the approach is the same. There are different (possibly shorter) syntax variants to do this, but none of them will allow to do this by iteration with a loop.

I would recommend
class Test {
  constructor(
    public a1,
    public a2,
    public a3,
    public a4,
    public a5,
  ) {}
}

then use spread syntax to call it:
function createNewTestObject(param) {
  return new Test(...param);
}

